# Google Big Query - Calculating monthly totals by status based on multiple date conditionals

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table with the following data:

```
    customer_id     subscription_id     plan      status     trial_start     trial_end      activated_at   cancelled_at

        1               jg1             basic    cancelled    2020-06-26     2020-07-14      2020-07-14     2020-09-25
        
        2               ab1             basic    cancelled    2020-08-10     2020-08-24      2020-08-24     2021-02-15

        3               cf8             basic    cancelled    2020-08-25     2020-09-04      2020-09-04     2020-10-24
                    
        4               bc2             basic     active      2020-10-12     2020-10-26      2020-10-26
                
        5               hg4             basic     active      2021-01-09     2021-02-08      2021-02-08
            
        6               cd5             basic    in-trial     2021-02-26
```

As you notice from the table, `status = in_trial` when a subscription is in trial. When subscription converts from `in_trial` to `active` there is `activated_at` date. When an `in_trial` or `active` subscription is cancelled, status switches to `cancelled` and `cancelled_at` date is present. `Status` column always shows only most recent status of a subscription. For every change in status a new row **does not** appear for subscription. For every change in status, status is changed, and appropriate dates appear to reflect time when status was changed.

My goal is to calculate, month-over-month, how many subscriptions are in `status = in_trial`, how many are in `status = active` and how many are in `status = cancelled`. Because status column reflects the most recent status of subscription, a query has to be able to determine how many subscriptions were in `status = in_trial`, `status = active`, and `status = active` based on available dates column.

If a particular subscription had multiple statuses in a given month (for example, `subscription_id = ab1` was in trial in Aug-2020 and also converted to active in Aug-2020), I want only the most recent status to be considered for that subscription. So, as example, for `subscription_id = ab1` I want it to be counted as `active` subscription for the month of Aug-2020.

The output I am looking for is:

```
    date          in_trial   active    cancelled
   2020-06-01         1        0           0
   2020-07-01         0        1           0
   2020-08-01         1        2           0
   2020-09-01         0        2           1         
   2020-10-01         0        2           1 
   2020-11-01         0        2           0
   2020-12-01         0        2           0 
   2021-01-01         1        2           0
   2021-02-01         1        2           1
   2021-03-01         1        2           0
```

Or, results can be displayed in a different format, as long as numbers are correct. Another example of output can be:

```
   date           status      count
2020-06-01       in_trial       1
2020-06-01        active        0
2020-06-01       cancelled      0
2020-07-01       in_trial       0
2020-07-01        active        1
2020-07-01       cancelled      0
   ...             ...         ...
2021-03-01       in_trial       1
2021-03-01        active        2
2021-03-01       cancelled      0
```

Below is the query you can use to reproduce the example table provided in this question:

```
SELECT 1 AS customer_id, 'jg1' AS subscription_id, 'basic' AS plan, 'cancelled' AS status, '2020-06-26' AS trial_start, '2020-07-14' AS trial_end, '2020-07-14' AS activated_at, '2020-09-25' AS cancelled_at UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS customer_id, 'ab1' AS subscription_id, 'basic' AS plan, 'cancelled' AS status, '2020-08-10' AS trial_start, '2020-08-24' AS trial_end, '2020-08-24' AS activated_at, '2021-02-15' AS cancelled_at UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS customer_id, 'cf8' AS subscription_id, 'basic' AS plan, 'cancelled' AS status, '2020-08-25' AS trial_start, '2020-09-04' AS trial_end, '2020-09-04' AS activated_at, '2020-10-24' AS cancelled_at UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS customer_id, 'bc2' AS subscription_id, 'basic' AS plan, 'active' AS status, '2020-10-12' AS trial_start, '2020-10-26' AS trial_end, '2020-10-26' AS activated_at, '' AS cancelled_at UNION ALL 
SELECT 5 AS customer_id, 'hg4' AS subscription_id, 'basic' AS plan, 'active' AS status, '2021-01-09' AS trial_start, '2021-02-08' AS trial_end, '2021-02-08' AS activated_at, '' AS cancelled_at UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 AS customer_id, 'cd5' AS subscription_id, 'basic' AS plan, 'in_trial' AS status, '2021-02-26' AS trial_start, '' AS trial_end, '' AS activated_at, '' AS cancelled_at
```

I have been working on this problem since yesterday morning and continuing to figure out a way to do this efficiently. Thank you in advance for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: clarify - is it `'' AS trial_end` or `null AS trial_end`  ?

Comment: '' is meant to represent a null value. Good question - I should have made this more clear.

Comment: so in your reproduce query - it should be `null` instead of `''` - right? not super important, but makes a difference for further coding. also your date related columns - are they string or of date type?

Comment: Correct, it should be null instead of empty strings. As of date columns, they are date-time in my actual data, with precision down to a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work for you

```
select month, 
  count(distinct if(status = 0, customer_id, null)) in_trial, 
  count(distinct if(status = 1, customer_id, null)) active, 
  count(distinct if(status = 2, customer_id, null)) canceled
from (
  select month, customer_id, 
    array_agg(status order by status desc limit 1)[offset(0)] status
  from (
    select distinct customer_id, 0 status, date_trunc(date, month) month
    from `project.dataset.table`,
    unnest(generate_date_array(date(trial_start), ifnull(date(trial_end), current_date()))) date 
      union all
    select distinct customer_id, 1 status, date_trunc(date, month) month
    from `project.dataset.table`,
    unnest(generate_date_array(date(activated_at), ifnull(date(cancelled_at), current_date()))) date 
      union all
    select distinct customer_id, 2 status, date_trunc(date(cancelled_at), month) month
    from `project.dataset.table`
)
where not month is null
group by month, customer_id
)
group by month
# order by month
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail, I am analyzing this now to understand the query. I will let you know if I will have any questions and will be my pleasure to upvote and select as best answer once the solution is clear to me

Comment: sure, in short - 1) it has three most inner queries each for separate daily status 2) next select calculates which status was the last in the given moth for each user 3) and finally - most outer select just does simple final aggregation of distinct customers per month for each of three subscription statuses :o)

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail, I tried this on a subset of my data and works very well. One question - if, for example, instead of number of companies I would want to calculate number of subscriptions, and a company may have more than 1 subscription, how would I do that? Playing with your query now to try to figure this out